# DiscordJS v14s slashCommand in text with function

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to know how to do this on bot with the corresponding command when you click it. I know how to make this kind of text by doing `</text_here:0>` but it has no function, so, if you know how to make this kind of text on Discord.js v14, please kindly tell me how to do this. It would be great for me and others who want to know how to make this:

[image: dank_memer_sell]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really have anything to do with Discord.js, everyone can type a command in chat like that with </`command_name`:`command_id`> as you can see here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#message-formatting

So, for example `</help:1001206362895826989>`

To get the command ID, go into server settings -> integrations -> your bot -> right click the command and copy the id.

If you want to use subcommands too you can use </`command_name` `subcommand`:`command_id`>

and an example for this is `\</help general:1001206362895826989\>`

Comment: Sorry for this late reply but I was wondering... could you get this command id using or directly on Discordjs?

Comment: I think so, `<Client>.application.commands.cache` should show you all your bot's commands, get one then get it's ID.
Here you have more info about `<Client>.application.commands`: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ApplicationCommandManager